# bigint type with & usage

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, bigint

I am seeing this first time using '`&`' symbol in sql stored procedures.

```
declare  @b bigint
set @b=15
select @b&2

result is 2
```

Can some one explain me how the result was 2??

FYI: its on SQL server 2005

Answer (score 3):

`&` is the [Bitwise And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) operator.

The result is 2 because;

```
select 15     --15 as binary: 1111
       & 2    --2 as binary:  0010
                              ----
  --AND'ing the bits yields;  0010  <- decimal 2
```

Comment: thanks for the response. seems like I lost the fundamentals about bits calculation. Can you give me some brief explanation or direct me to some tutorials, to find out how the binary numbers get formed??

Answer (score 0):

The `&` symbol is performs a bitwise logical AND operation between two integer values.

Are you trying to add 2, in which case you may be looking to use:

```
declare @b bigint set @b=15 select @b + 2
```